# Bag difference (similar to setdiff() but not for sets)

Tags: r, set, subtraction

In R, is there some easy way to do multi-set (i.e. "bag") differences, similar to `setdiff()`, but preserving order and multiplicity in the input vectors?

For example, suppose `x <- c(1,2,2,3,1,5,4,4,5,3)` and `y <- c(2,1,5,5)`.  I'm looking for a function `bagdiff()` such that `bagdiff(x,y)` is `c(2,3,1,4,4,3)`, i.e. the first occurrences of elements of `y` in `x` have been deleted, with multiplicity.

(In my actual task I won't really care about the order of the output, so it only matters that the multiplicity is correct, but the general ordered case does seem worth solving.)

Answer (score 3):

There's a [sets](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/index.html) module that comes close to what you describe. Something like:

```
library(sets)
gset_difference(as.gset(x), as.gset(y)) 
# gives
{1 [1], 2 [1], 3 [2], 4 [2]}
```

Comment: Thanks - is there a method to turn that `gset` result back into a regular vector?  Or should I use something like `rep(unlist(gs), times=gset_memberships(gs))`?

Comment: I couldn't find any other way to do it. A function like that seems like a nice addition to that package. Note that the membership is not always an integer.